# JSON - delete filtered item from parent object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object (although for this example I am going to hard-code it into the example) and I would like to delete an item based on its key `item`.
I do not want to use the `delete [index]` method.

How could I filter my list to get the key-value pair I would like to remove, and then delete that entry only.

I have tried the below but it doesn't work.

(I am using Javascript)

Thanks

```
name_array = [
{"item": 1, "name": "John"}, 
{"item": 2, "name": "Barry"}, 
{"item": 3, "name": "Sally"}
]

filtered_array = name_array.filter((i) => i.item == 2)
delete filtered_array[0]
console.log(name_array)
```

Comment: You should make the filter predicate match all array elements that you want to keep, i.e. not match the one you want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is immutable so you should console `filtered_array` value its working. No need to use  `delete`. And change the condition `==` to `!==`

```js
name_array = [{
    "item": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "item": 2,
    "name": "Barry"
  },
  {
    "item": 3,
    "name": "Sally"
  }
]

filtered_array = name_array.filter((i) => i.item !== 2)
console.log(filtered_array)
```